# Basis, null space, row space, column space

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $A = \begin{bmatrix}
1&1&-1&0  
\\3&-1&2&-4   
\\-1&2&-4&3
\end{bmatrix}$ I need to calate the following:

1) Find a basis for the null space and the nullity of A.
2) Find a basis for the row space and the row rank of A.
3) Find a basis for the column space and the column rank of A.

So I brought the matrix $A$ in row echelon form:

$\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&-1&0  
\\0&1&0&0   
\\0&0&1&0
\end{bmatrix}$ I believe I did this part correctly.

So I know the rank of this matrix $A$ is 3 and it has 3 pivot points. Looking for some help with  these questions

Comment: You are correct, this matrix is of rank $3$.

Comment: Do you already know the rank-nullity theorem, also known (perhaps in a little more advanced degree) as the dimensions theorem?

Comment: rank + nullity = n is a formula i know

Comment: How do i go about solving these problems?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just reduce the matrix ? its not more work and often makes things easier.

\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0  
\\0&1&0&0   
\\0&0&1&0
\end{bmatrix}

1) We see that the row and column rank (they are always equal) are $3$.
The nullity $=n-$rank$=4-3=1$.
To find the null space we have to solve $A\mathbf{x}=0$, and this is easy now in row reduced form $\mathbf{x}=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\0\\a
\end{bmatrix}$.

2) The row space has dimension $3$ as mentioned, for the basis one can take:
$$(1,0,0,0)$$
$$(0,1,0,0)$$
$$(0,0,1,0)$$

Or one could take the rows of the original matrix, since the rank is $3$.

3) The column rank is also $3$ row reduction has not changed the column vectors, just expressed them in a different basis so a basis for the column space will be the first $3$ vectors of the original matrix (corresponding to the pivot position of the reduced matrix):

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1\\3\\-1
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\-1\\2
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\2\\-4\\
\end{bmatrix}. $$

Comment: did you just take my reduced matrix and reduce the first row even farther?

Comment: Yes, and it wasnt any work at all !

Comment: awesome thanks for your time, that makes things easier when reduced like that

Comment: @ Rene Schipperus for b) is that supposed to be a matrix or is it supposed to be in the form that you wrote it?

Comment: Do you mean for 2) ? That is three vectors. Not sure I understand what your asking.

Comment: @ Rene Schipperus sorry I understand what you did now. For number 3 the original column vectors is a basis for the column space and the column rank of A?

Comment: Yes, for taking the column basis you want to return to the corresponding vectors in the original matrix.

Comment: okay awesome thanks that makes sense now

Comment: @ Rene Schipperus if i was to verify that rankA + null(A) = the number of columns of A, I know that the rank of A is 3 and the null is 1 so 3+ 1 = 4 which is equal to the number of columns of A, Would this be enough for a solution for the equation?

Comment: Yes I thiink so, by the way your row reduction is wrong, the fourth column is non zero, you might want to check this.

Comment: @ Rene Schipperus okay i will check this, but your row reduction you have worked out is correct?

Comment: Well no, I just took your matrix and went a step further, the first three columns are right but the last one is wrong.

Comment: oh no that will mean everything we have done is incorrect

Comment: @ Rene Schipperus would it be possible for you to make a edit?

Comment: I dont really feel like doing that, but you can correct your question...

Comment: any way not much changes all the steps  are correct and the same just the last column changes.

Comment: @ Rene Schipperus okay so everything remains the same for 1 2 3 4 even with the new column 4?

Comment: @ Rene Schipperus sorry i did make a mistake it should be -1 1 0 for the entries in column 4. But this would not change the row(a) = col(a) = 3 correct?

Comment: I think thats right.

Comment: okay thanks again